# Getting the total of unit price * quantity

Tags: python, django, annotations, sum

Here's an excerpt from my models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    ...
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
```

I have a dashboard where I want to display the total of sold items. I am struggling with how I can multiply the `unit_price` by the `quantity`.

Comment: Is this just something you want at the `OrderItem` level? Or do you want to get a total sum (unit_price * quantity) for all `OrderItem`s on an `Order`?

Comment: @pcoronel at the OrderItem level, not per order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could do this with an `extra()` query:

   ```
   OrderItem.objects.extra(select={'total': 'unit_price * quantity'})
   ```
2. You could add a property `total` to `OrderItem`:

   ```
   class OrderItem(models.Model):
       ...
       unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
       quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()

       @property
       def total(self):
           return unit_price * quantity

   # you can then access it like any other field (but you cannot filter on it)
   print OrderItem.objects.get(pk=1).total
   ```